# Why my calculation does not match metatrader 4 backtest loss?

Tags: metatrader4, back-testing

I am writing and expert advisor and ran a test. And I cannot understand, and find info why loss amount is not matching my calculations. To do backtesting I should get correct results.

[image]

So in the image we see there was 0.79 lot position opened at 109.87 closed at 109.939.

[image]

Here is the position size calculator showing swap.
[image]

But when backtesting I am getting even lower swap. Maybe calculator indicator is showing wrong. With lower swap the gap between expected loss and actual loss is even bigger.

[image]

So daily swap eats 6.15 usd. Account is in usd. From jan 22 to feb 6 it has been 17 swaps. Commision as you will see below in log is 3.16.

So my math is 6.15*17+52.5+3.16=160.21

but position loss is 175.48.

I also have printed swap each day:

```
2020.11.30 20:55:10.728 2020.02.06 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -98.7114401
2020.11.30 20:55:10.728 2020.02.05 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -81.29177420000001
2020.11.30 20:55:10.727 2020.02.04 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -75.48521890000001
2020.11.30 20:55:10.727 2020.02.03 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -69.67866360000001
2020.11.30 20:55:10.727 2020.01.31 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -63.87210830000001
2020.11.30 20:55:10.721 2020.01.30 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -58.06555300000001
2020.11.30 20:55:10.721 2020.01.29 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -40.6458871
2020.11.30 20:55:10.721 2020.01.28 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -34.8393318
2020.11.30 20:55:10.720 2020.01.27 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -29.0327765
2020.11.30 20:55:10.720 2020.01.24 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -23.2262212
2020.11.30 20:55:10.720 2020.01.23 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: swap: -17.41966590000001
2020.11.30 20:55:10.719 2020.01.22 00:00:00 adx USDJPY,H1: commission -3.16
```

and it shows about 5.8 for one day. Which would make even bigger gap if I would use it for my calculation.